# How to select the button randomly selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

this is my button  xpath id in here how can i code randomly select one button? 
**(note:- correct my English and grammar)**

```
button1= xpath id is ( html/body/div[3]/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1])
button2= xpath id is ( html/body/div[3]/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2])
button3= xpath id is ( html/body/div[3]/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3])
button3= xpath id is ( html/body/div[3]/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4])
```

for example

```
if button1 is randomly select 
{   code 
}
else button2 is randomly select 
{   code
}
else button3 is randomly select 
{   code
}
```

Comment: Can you please share ur HTML DOM

Comment: check this link  i want code random select that button [link]https://www.easybooking.lk/listing/tomstome (im working this site as a QA )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.Next(1, 5);  // 1 <= index < 5

xpath = ( html/body/div[3]/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div[index])
```